# What are the two orange tabs stuck on opposite edges of each window of the ISS cupola?

Tags: iss, identify-this-object, spacecraft-window

The YouTube video [ONE OF THE MOST DETAILED ISS TOUR!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvTmdIhYnes) is cited in several Q&A here, and shows a tour and explanation of the ISS by astronaut Steven Swanson.

Today I noticed between `28:30` and `31:20` that each of the seven windows in the ISS cupola shows a pair of orange stick-on tabs on opposite edges of the glass. Sunlight can be seen through them, showing what looks like four circuit board traces and three "pads".

What is the function of these devices, what do they connect to, and have they always been there?

I'm guessing they are not for security or burglar detection.

[image]

[image]

**above x2:** Screenshots from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvTmdIhYnes), first is zoomed/sharpened.

Comment: Those traces make me think of thermistors. Maybe the temperature of the glass is measured here?

Comment: @Dragongeek: I agree, it may be an [RTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_thermometer#Pt) in four wire configuration for temperature measurement.

Comment: "Thanks", @uhoh! I've never noticed those tabs before and now I see them in every picture! :)  Like the "cue dots" in old films, once my projectionist friend showed them to me, I could never un-see them.

Comment: @OrganicMarble exactly, me too, same thing (re windows, not cue dots, but now that you mention it...) Perhaps it's a glitch in the matrix type thing.

Comment: I swear: the clouds in that photo still appear to be moving.

Comment: peel off tabs to get to the tasty astronaut treats inside

Comment: Probably just hinges to open the windows when it gets hot on the ISS... ;-)

Comment: @agtoever Yes I am sure you are right. A pair is placed with one opposite the other for redundancy no doubt.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are part of the cupola window temperature control system. Each window has window heaters and temperature sensing modules (these orange tabs) to make sure the windows don't get too hot or too cold. For example, if the window gets too hot, the astronauts would be instructed to close the cupola's shutters. Because of the traces I assume that each orange sticker contains two thermistors for redundancy or is simply a four wire sensor such as an RTD.

https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/i/iss-cupola

Comment: I disagree, not two sensors, but one in four wire configuration. Using the four wire circuit for resistance measurement, the influence of cable resistance to the result of sensor resistance could be made to almost zero.

Comment: A RTD is not necessarily a four wire sensor. A RTD may be used in two, three or four wire configuration, but the temperature sensor itself is a resistor with two connections.

Comment: Can you find the place in your link that mentions that these tabs are part of the temperature sensing system? I don't doubt it, more likely than strain gauges or anything else I can think of, but right now it seems to be just an educated guess. Thanks!

Comment: The reference does not support your answer as far as I can tell.

Comment: My former colleague Robert Frost says they are RTDs here https://www.quora.com/What-if-the-windows-in-the-ISS-Cupola-got-over-heated

Comment: @uhoh Under primary hardware  "thermistors" are listed as part of the window assembly. Judging by the amount of detail on the page, I don't see what else they could be.

Comment: I've just asked [How do you replace an ISS window assembly on orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31988/12102)

Comment: @Uwe is right - you can see the 2 leads of the single platinum wire resistor connecting to the U-turns of the 4 ribbon traces.

Comment: @Dragongeek Can you consider adding OrganicMarble's Quora reference into your answer as well? I think it adds to your answer, which I am sure is 100% correct already. Since comments are considered temporary/ephemeral, it's always good to bring helpful, supporting information back into the main post.