# How (the heck) do you replace a space station window in orbit?

Tags: iss, spacecraft-window

The eoPortal document [Cupola Observation Module of the ISS](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/i/iss-cupola) found in @Dragongeek's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31985/12102) to *What are the two orange tabs stuck on opposite edges of each window of the ISS cupola?* has some interesting items and references. One of them reads:

> Hardware (secondary)
>   - 2 Window Change Out Covers to support on orbit window assembly replacement

How *do you* replace an ISS window assembly on orbit?

Comment: The Cupola is probably a special case. You can close the CBM hatch behind it and allow it to vent to vacuum and then pressurize it when you are done. I doubt they ever want too!  Also, probably has an inner window and outer window, both of which are sufficient in the short term to hold out the vacuum.  I.e. Change the outer, inner protects. Change the inner, outer protects.

Comment: Seems like they [did it last year](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2017/04/crew-replace-cupola-window-iss/). Reading that, it seems it's just the outer sacrificial pane that they swap out once it gets too damaged.

Comment: @DanMašek per your link: "In the event of the damage being more serious, **on-orbit replacement of an entire window** is a design feature." it seems it isn't always just the outer pane.

Comment: @uhoh I'd assume it would go down the same as when they found the drill-hole. Seal off the module, find the source, assess the damage and attempt repairs (likely using an EVA). They could even seal off more than one module to make a make-shift airlock then send someone in. Didn't they seal off the Zvedza module to prevent further station depressurization in that drill-hole event? Which means you'd basically have a dead-weight inoperable module until you do the repairs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The plan for replacement of an entire window is a bit surprising. It would not be done by closing the cupola hatch and depressurizing the cupola - although such a hatch does exist. (in the picture 1 = hatch track, 2 = the hatch).

[image]

(image - NASA, annotations mine)

Instead, an external pressure cover would be fitted to the outside of the window by astronauts performing an EVA.  Then the window would be swapped out from inside the cupola.

Sources

- [ESA Cupola description pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20070315232107/http://www.spaceflight.esa.int/documents/cupola/cupola-what.pdf)
- [ESA Cupola webpage](https://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Human_and_Robotic_Exploration/Node-3_Cupola/Cupola/(print))

[This](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2017/04/crew-replace-cupola-window-iss/) reference states that the external pressure covers are not stored on orbit but must be carried up on demand by one of the logistics vehicles.

Comment: That's terrifying, do they seal the internal hatch during the replacement just in case the replacement goes awry? I'd hate to say it but if you could lose one person in case of the pressure cover failure, it's much better than the whole station (0 losses is far more acceptable).

Comment: I haven't found the actual procedure sadly. I'm sure a lot of leak checking would be done.

Comment: If the external pressure cover is fitted to the outside of the window, pressure on both sides of the window should be equalized before it is possible to remove the old window. So there should be an equalization valve for each window within the cupola structure

Comment: just fyi the recent question [Apparently the ISS cupola windows are Replaceable in orbit. What is the pressure hatch design and procedure?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/65319/12102) is based on the `www.spaceflight.esa.int/documents/cupola/cupola-what.pdf` link apparently being broken. I wonder if this is a suitable replacement? http://wsn.spaceflight.esa.int/docs/Factsheets/4%20Cupola%20HR%20web.pdf

Comment: @uhoh the pdf is still available here - it might not be the doc you thought it was? https://web.archive.org/web/20070315232107/http://www.spaceflight.esa.int/documents/cupola/cupola-what.pdf

Comment: @blobbymcblobby thanks - nothing is ever what I think it is ;-)

Comment: @blobbymcblobby thanks for the link to the archived pdf. I've replaced it in the text. Damn these space agencies and their web page policies! :)